# facebook installed something, it is not showing anywhere

Tags: facebook, installation

2 days ago i got a https request from facebook.
Now i am getting wierd notifications when some one message me on facebook.
I am pretty sure this is ilegal.
I gave no permission also i dit not read any thing about it.
And i want it gone, can any one help me?
It is not showing anywhere, not in chrome://plugins chrome://settings  or windows programs.
i dont have time to search for it and get nowhere...
if some one has the knowledge of this installation please respond, many thanks.

Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by `https request from facebook`. This looks so absurd that I'm thinking of marking it as spam.

Comment: @vish4071 anyway...its not an ideal question here.

Comment: `Weird notifications` sounds weird!!

Comment: Or maybe now I understand what he is saying...about FB's new feature where it has started with desktop notifications.

Comment: Define "weird notifications",  what do they look like?

Comment: They look like Chrome system notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are confusing (one of the new features of FB) desktop notifications with something.

Firstly, its not illegal.

Secondly, I'm very sure that you have allowed it yourself.

**How to remove it:**

- Open facebook.
- Click on the lock in the address bar (where you type the url). You should see the lock before `https://` (from where url starts).
- You can see the `Permissions` tab there, which should show:

  Notifications: Allowed by you.

Click on it and disable it.

Comment: Thank u, i tought they installed a plugin, and i only got a https notify, i did not get any explanation.

Comment: I am tricked in enabling this function, and i am still pretty sure it is illegal, i was not at facebook when i was receiving these messages, so it is software related. it prob used chome notify system. Witch i gave no permission for to use.

Comment: Actually that's how desktop notifications work. You are signed in to FB (whether or not the tab is open does not matter), that is enough. If you will disable that, it is fine and you won't receive them.

Comment: When i close facebook, i dont want a open connection to facebook to exist, i want it to close when i close the site, i am pretty sure facebook should give more info when tricking ppl to enable this. 
This message/notify system means there is still a connection, i did not approve of.

Comment: When you sign in into any site (FB, gmail, youtube, SO or any other for that matter), a `Session` is opened which does not end until you `log-out` of that session. Closing a tab does not end the `session`, so, an open connection exists. If you don't want that, you should logout first before closing the tab.

Comment: Your Talking to a web designer, php javascript asp html ect ect....
When i close the site, there should be no connection left.
a cookie cant process data by itself.